# Problem with DependencyProperty in custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, dependency-properties

In my code I have declared, within the custom control ValidatingTextBox, the following dependency property:

```
public DependencyProperty visibleText = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("visText", typeof(String), typeof(ValidatingTextBox));
public String visText
{
    get { return theBox.Text; }
    set { theBox.Text = value; }
}
```

But when I try to use the xaml

```
<local:ValidatingTextBox>
    <ValidatingTextBox.visibleText>

    </ValidatingTextBox.visibleText>
</local:ValidatingTextBox>
```

it says that such a dependencyproperty doesn't exist within ValidatingTextBox.  What am I doing wrong?  Is there a better way to interact with the child text box of my custom control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the register method you registered it as `visText`, the name of the field does not have anything to do with the property itself. You also seem to define an attached property which is going to be used like a normal property, you should define it as a normal dependency-property.

Further you create two properties, a depedency property without a CLR-wrapper and a normal property by doing this:

```
public String visText
{
    get { return theBox.Text; }
    set { theBox.Text = value; }
}
```

It has nothing to do with the value of your actual depedency property since it never accesses it. Besides that the property field should be static and readonly.

Reading through the [Depedency Properties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) is advised as this is quite a mess, also have  a look at [the article on creating custom dependency properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx) which should be quite helpful.

---

To address your question of how to interact with the child controls: Create (proper) dependency properties and bind to them.

Since the property already exists on the child you can also reuse it with [`AddOwner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.DependencyProperty.AddOwner.aspx):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
    TextBox.TextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyControl));
public string Text
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
}
```

```xml
<!-- Assuming a usercontrol rather than a custom control -->
<!-- If you have a custom control and the child controls are created in code you can do the binding there -->
<UserControl ...
      Name="control">
    <!-- ... -->
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=control}"/>
    <!-- ... -->
</UserControl>
```